# UILabel subclass initialize with custom color

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, subclass

My goal is to set the `textColor` of my custom `UILabel` subclass in my view controller. I have a `UILabel` subclass named `CircleLabel`. Here are the basics of it:

```
class CircleLabel: UILabel {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width/2
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    super.drawRect(rect)
}

override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
    self.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    super.drawTextInRect(rect)
}

func setProperties(borderWidth: Float, borderColor: UIColor) {
    self.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(borderWidth)
    self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
}
```

}

As you can see, every CircleLabel I instantiate is defaulted to a textColor property of UIColor.whiteColor(), which works properly. In my view controller's viewDidLoad, I want to set my CircleLabel to have a dynamic `textColor` property. So something like this:

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myCustomLabel: CircleLabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myCustomLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

That doesn't work because `textColor` is set in the `drawRect` method of the `UILabel` subclass. What can I implement in my `CircleLabel` subclass (via a helper method like my setProperties helper method or some other way) that would allow me to set the `textColor` of my custom label in my view controller?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Screenshot

[image]

You do not need to override `drawRect` in your case,just create the class like this

```
class CircleLabel: UILabel {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.commonInit()

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit(){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width/2
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.setProperties(1.0, borderColor:UIColor.blackColor())
    }
    func setProperties(borderWidth: Float, borderColor: UIColor) {
        self.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(borderWidth)
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
    }
}
```

Then

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myCustomLabel: CircleLabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myCustomLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you take the same approach to override the "font" of a label that contains an Attributed Text? Like taking the current attributed text in the "common in" and overriding it with a mutable copy of it which contains a different font. (Just wondering if it would work since you have experience in it and i'm looking for this myself)

Comment: I get `Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass` when using `override init` on the `UILabel`

Answer (score 1):

**1. Custom Label In swift**

```
    class CustomLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 7.0
    @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 7.0

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: size.width + leftInset + rightInset,
                      height: size.height + topInset + bottomInset)
    }
}
```